# Sybase and jdbc- Proc returns select statement - records not able to get

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, sybase

I'm executing a stored procedure from jdbc. The procedure returns the contents of a table 'out_table' which consists of 2 columns key and value, via select query.

I'm using

```
String query = "{? = call my_proc}";
    try {
    stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.JAVA_OBJECT);
    boolean results = stmt.execute();

    while (results) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        if(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("MSG"));
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("SEQ"));
        }
    }
```

I'm not able to get any results. I can see a lot of example that returns only a single field of a table from proc and not the whole table. The type 'Types.JAVA_OBJECT', I'm not sure what to use. For me, the output table fields are string and int, respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

Note : my_proc:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #tmp_table
(
    MSG VARCHAR(255),
    SEQ INT
)
//Insert contents into #tmp_table
..
..
..
SELECT * FROM #tmp_table ORDER BY SEQ
END
go
```

Comment: does you stored procedure return something? could you post your code of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure doesn't have an out parameter. It produces a `ResultSet` instead. So you should remove the out parameter definition in your call:

```
String query = "{call my_proc}";
try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query)) {
    boolean results = stmt.execute();
    while (true) {
       if (results) {
           // results true means: result is ResultSet
           try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {
               if(rs.next()) {
                   System.out.println(rs.getString("MSG"));
                   System.out.println(rs.getInt("SEQ"));
               }
           }
       } else {
           // results false means: result is update count
           // or no more results if updateCount is -1
           int updateCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
           if (updateCount == -1) break;
           // Do something with update count
       }
       // Move to next result
       results = stmt.getMoreResults()
    }
 }
```

I added try-with-resource to correctly close resource as soon as you are done with them, I have also added code to correctly handle multiple results including update counts, which especially in Sybase (and SQL Server) might be a complication if your stored procedure doesn't use `SET NOCOUNT ON`. Your original code also had an infinite loop.

Note that `if(rs.next())` might need to be `while (rs.next)` if there can be more than one result in the table.